# Python labeling Expression how to change font size?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, typeerror

I have a labeling expression using two attributes I want the first one to be size 14 and the second one to be on a new line and be size 8. This was my attempt so far:

```
"<FNT name='Arial' size='14'>" & [Sec_Unit_L] & "</FNT>" +  "\n" + "<FNT name='Arial' size='8'>" & [TWP_Label]  & "</FNT>"
```

I get the following error message

[image]

Comment: Are you using the python or VB parser? Your question says python but your concatenation is VB.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few [formatting tags](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/using-text-formatting-tags-about-text-formatting-t.htm) for ArcGIS, in either python or VB parser they are the same:

In VB:

```
"<FNT size='14'>" & [Sec_Unit_L] & "</FNT>" + vbnewline + "<FNT size='8'>" & [TWP_Label] & "</FNT>"
```

In Python:

```
"<FNT size='14'>{}</FNT>\n<FNT size='8'>{}</FNT>".format([Sec_Unit_L],[TWP_Label])
```

Whenever you open an enclosure you must close it, in this case `<FNT XXX>` matches a closing `</FNT>` otherwise the opening enclosure doesn't change the text but gets printed in the label.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I confusing myself by using a bit VB in a Python expression. Thanks again

Comment: @rockycove The best way to say "thanks" here is to upvote and/or accept the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)